# Eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix that is a product of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, linear-regression

In linear regression model, we have
$$
y=X\beta+\epsilon, 
$$
where $y,X$ and $\epsilon$ are random vector/matrices of dimension $n\times 1$, $n\times r$ and $n\times 1$ respectively

In computing the OLS estimator, we will ecounter the matrix $X'X$ that is symmetric and invertible where $X$ is the matrix of data. In computing the variance of OLS estimator, we often ecounter the matrix $X'\Omega X$, where $\Omega$ is the covariance matrix that is postive definite and symmetric.

Can we obtain some bounds on the eigenvalue in terms of $\lambda(X'X)$ or $\text{tr}(X'X)$ and $\lambda(\Omega)$? Currently, I can get a bound like $\lambda(X)^2 \lambda(\Omega)$ if $X$ is also symmetric.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\lambda(X)$? Is that the largest eigenvalue of $X$?

Comment: Just means the eigenvalue of $X$. So any eigenvalues of $X$ including the maximum would be fine for me

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about "the eigenvalue" of a matrix that has multiple eigenvalues, but I think I understand what you're trying to say

Comment: Sorry for being a bit sloppy with my language. What I really mean is any eigenvalue of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upper bound can be extended to the more general
$$
\lambda_{\max}(X'\Omega X) \leq \lambda_{\max}(X'X)\lambda_{\max}(\Omega).
$$
The matrix $X'\Omega X$ is positive semidefinite, so all of its eigenvalues are non-negative with the above upper bound.

This can be shown as follows. Let $\|X\| = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(X'X)}$ denote the spectral norm of $X$. We have
\begin{align}
\lambda_{\max}(X'\Omega X) &= \max_{\|v\| \leq 1} v'(X'\Omega X)v
= \max_{\|v\| \le 1} (Xv)'\Omega (Xv) 
\\ & = \|X\|^2 \max_{\|v\| \leq 1} \left(\frac{Xv}{\|X\|} \right)' \Omega \left(\frac{Xv}{\|X\|} \right)
\\ & \leq \|X\|^2 \max_{\|w\| \leq 1} w'\Omega w = \|X\|^2 \cdot \lambda_{\max}(\Omega).
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry to comment after a while. I notice this after accepting it. Do you mean \begin{align}
&  \|Xv\|^2 \max_{\|v\| \leq 1} \left(\frac{Xv}{\|Xv\|} \right)' \Omega \left(\frac{Xv}{\|Xv\|} \right)
\\ & \leq \|X\|^2 \max_{\|w\| \leq 1} w'\Omega w = \|X\|^2 \cdot \lambda_{\max}(\Omega).
\end{align} instead?

Comment: @chuck No I do not. $\|Xv\|$ doesn't make sense outside of the max argument

Comment: I see. Could you explain the inequality step for me. Thanks.

Comment: $$
\left\|\frac{Xv}{\|X\|} \right\| = \frac{\|Xv\|}{\|X\|} \leq \frac{\|X\| \cdot \|v\|}{\|X\|} = \|v\| \leq 1.
$$
So, the inequality holds because we are maximizing over a larger set. We are considering $w'\Omega w$ not only for vectors $w$ of the form $w = \frac{Xv}{\|X\|}$ with $\|v\| \leq 1$, but for all vectors $w$ for which $\|w\| \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got caught up with the submultiplicative  property and forgot about this.

Comment: @chuck In a sense, your approach could also work. We have
$$
\begin{align} &  \max_{\|v\| \leq 1} \|Xv\|^2 \left(\frac{Xv}{\|Xv\|} \right)' \Omega \left(\frac{Xv}{\|Xv\|} \right) \\ & \leq  \max_{\|w\| \leq 1} \|X\|^2 w'\Omega w = 
\|X\|^2\max_{\|w\| \leq 1}  w'\Omega w = 
\|X\|^2 \cdot \lambda_{\max}(\Omega). \end{align}
$$